# SQL Query that checks only numeric characters in the database

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a legacy system a client has. Phone numbers are stored in a multitude of ways. Ex:

```
514-879-9989
514.989.2289
5147899287
```

The client wants to be able to search the database by phone number.

How could this be achieved without normalizing the data stored in the database? Is this possible?

I am wondering if it is possible to have a query that looks like:

```
SELECT FROM table WHERE phonenumber LIKE %input%
```

but that takes into account only the numerical characters in the db?

Comment: What is the complete range of formats? Eg, are there international formats like `"+1 (514) 879-9898"`? Spaces as delimiters? Multi-character delimiters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I would take with this (i.e. not having a "normalized" value with only digits available, and a restriction of not adding an additional column with the normalized value...)

I would take the user input for the search, and add wild cards in strategic locations. For example, if the user provides search input of **`3155551212`**), then I'd run a query that has a predicate equivalent to this:

```
  phonenumber LIKE '%315%555%1212%'
```

But if I'm not guaranteed that the provided search digits will be a full three digit area code, a three digit exchange (central office) code, and a four digit line number, for a broader search, I'd add wild cards between all of the provided digits, e.g.

```
  phonenumber LIKE '%3%1%5%5%5%5%1%2%1%2%'
```

This latter approach is less than ideal, because it could potentially provide more matches than aren't intended. Especially if the user is providing fewer than ten digits. For example, consider a phonenumber value:

```
  '+1 (315) 555-7172 ext. 123'
```

As a demonstration:

```
SELECT '+1 (315) 555-7172 ext. 123' LIKE '%3%1%5%5%5%5%1%2%1%2%'
     , '+1 (315) 555-7172 ext. 123' LIKE '%315%555%1212%'
```

---

There's no builtin string function in MySQL that will extract the digit characters from a string.

If you want a function that does that, e.g.

```
 SELECT only_digits_from('+1 (315) 555-7172 ext. 123')
```

to return

```
 13155557172123
```

You'd have to create a stored function that does that. I wouldn't attempt doing it inline in the SQL statement, that would require an atrociously long and ugly  expression.

Comment: Used the first suggestion you wrote. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tab
WHERE replace(replace(phone, '.', ''), '-', '') like '%". $input ."%'"
```

Yes you can add more replace according to values in your table, as mentioned by @spencer7593 eg:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tab
WHERE replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(phone, '.', ''), '-', ''), '+', ''), '(', ''), ')', ''), ' ', '') like '%". $input ."%'"
```

but I would prefer to cleanup the data before the query.

Comment: This could be extended to handle other non-digit characters that may also appear, such as space, left and right parens, plus sign, 'x', et al. consider a phone number with leading country code and an extension e.g. `+1 (315) 555-1212 ext. 234`

Answer (score 0):

This is piece of code i frequently use to clean up the database columns. I have modified to to be fit for your purpose.

```
Update Table SET Column = 
replace
  (replace
    (replace(column,
    '-','',
  '.',''),
' ','')
)
```

WHERE Column is Not Null

Comment: Client does not want to normalize the db -_- I know I know lol

Comment: Oh ok. That slab of code should work in a select statement. Just use the code from the first replace to the last)  in a select statement